# not well-formed (invalid token) at line 15, column 51, byte 720 when trying to parse XMLRPC call

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm running WP 4.7.4. The site is a default site with no plugins activated other than the default plugins. I'm using the [`WordPress::XMLRPC`](http://search.cpan.org/~igibbs/WordPress-XMLRPC/lib/WordPress/XMLRPC.pod) Perl module to generate a `getPost` XMLRPC call for post #1 like so:

`my $obj = WordPress::XMLRPC->new({username => 'admin', password => 'xxxxxx', proxy => 'http://my.domain.com/'});`

`my $post = $obj->getPost(1);`

The full error is this:

> not well-formed (invalid token) at line 15, column 51, byte 720 at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
>   <head>
>   <...snip...>
>   </body>
>   </html>
>    at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/WordPress/XMLRPC.pm line 643.

Here is line 643 from `WordPress::XMLRPC`:

```
    my $call = $self->server->call(
            'metaWeblog.getPost',
            $post_id,
            $user_login,
            $user_pass,
    );
```

Here is line 187 from `XML::Parser` in an `eval` statement:

```
eval {
  $result = $expat->parse($arg);
};
```

Line 15 of the output is this:

> https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin rel='preconnect' />

When I run the output through this [XML validator,](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) I also get an error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 15 at column 52: Specification mandate value for attribute crossorigin

Answer (score 0):

Doh, I forgot to tack on `/xmlrpc.php` to the url. Should have been obvious because it was spitting back the home page.